# What is difference between "終わったり" and "終わり"? I can't find "終わったり" in English Japanese dictionary

Tags: meaning, conjugations

What is difference between "終わったり" and "終わり"? I can't find "終わったり" in English Japanese dictionary

Whole context link:https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=manga&illust_id=69898837

[image]

Comment: some of the posts here involving the verb ending たり might help you.